# Accessing index in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
err = abs(np.subtract(unNormalizedTestPredictions, test_labels))
print("max error", max(err) )
tmp = np.where( err > 300000) #tmp is a ndarray
print("large values located at ",tmp)
```

The output is:

**max error 334901.5078125
large values located at  (array([64828]),)**

How can I look at these large values ( err > 300000), and even better, find the value in test_labels that caused it?  I believe np.where tells me that it is at ndx 64828 but the following code blows up.  Could that same index be used in test_labels?

```
newarr = err[np.array([64828])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
new_array = test_labels[err> 300000]
```

To get all the values.

Note that `err> 300000` is a boolean array that will be `true` where the condition is validated. These index should match `test_labels`